Relationship of two different definitions of affine matrix
I find in some papers that the affine vectors are vectors the sum of whose entries are 1, and the affine matrices are matrices that preserve affinity, that is, every column is an affine vector. I know the definition of affine transfomations in Euclidean space. However, I cannot find the relationship of those two definitions. Under the latter definition, it is obvious that the inverse of an affine transformation is an affine transformation. But it seems not obvious under the former definition.

I'm not aware of these concepts of affine vectors/matrices. I'm also not sure how you are connecting affine transformations to the subject of matrices, but if it's the usual way using homogeneous coordinates, such matrices will not usually be affine matrices under the definition in the question.

The objects you are mentioning seem to be more related to convex geometry than affine. Basically affine is linear plus addition of some vector.

The set of affine matrices, as defined in the question, maps the hyperplane $x^1+\cdots+x^n=1$ to itself by affine transformations as defined I. The question.
